# Run Tomcat with a different port on the fly

Tags: tomcat

Is there a way to change the port while running Tomcat on the fly?

For example, Tomcat runs at the default 8080 port, is there a way **while launching** Tomcat using catalina.sh run to pass the port number as well?

Note: I know it is possible to make a change in the server.xml file to change the port, but I am asking about something while launching Tomcat (an argument to pass to catalina.sh for example).

Comment: I did, all the sources I found simply point me to changing the port int he server.xml file but nothing about changing it on the fly :)

Comment: What tomcat version are we talking about?

Comment: The most recent version of Tomcat (7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a tomcat `server.xml` configuration file with different port and pass it as an argument:

```
./bin/catalina.sh run -config conf/server9090.xml
```

Where in `conf/server9090.xml` you can set the port:

```
<Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

You can do it all with this one-liner:

```
 P=9090 ;sed "s/8080/$P/g" < conf/server.xml > /tmp/srv.xml && ./bin/catalina.sh run -config /tmp/srv.xml
```

Just change `P=9090` to the port you want.

Or put this script in `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ];then
    echo "Usage: $0 [port]"
    exit 1
fi
cd `dirname $0`
sed "s/8080/$1/g" < ../conf/server.xml > /tmp/server.xml \
    && ./catalina.sh run -config /tmp/server.xml
```

Make the script executable with `chmod +x ./bin/run.sh`

Then you can do `./bin/run.sh 9090`

Comment: I would like to be able to change it on the fly. Whenever launching Tomcat, launch with a port I pass as an argument for example.

Comment: Yes it is. See my answer below.

Comment: Example in a Dockerfile, just for fun. `RUN sed "s/8080/8081/g" < /tomcat/conf/server.xml > /tmp/server.xml` (line break)
`RUN cp /tmp/server.xml /tomcat/conf/server.xml` . Used this to change default port in [NetflixOSS ZeroToDocker demo for Asgard](https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/zerotodocker/blob/master/asgard/1.5.1/Dockerfile#L25).