# Change tomcat listening port using sed

Tags: bash, tomcat, sed

I am trying using `sed` to alter tomcat's `server.xml` and specifically the listening port in these lines

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

It is essential to do it though a `bash` script.
I am trying to variete the provided script (specifically the `sed` line) from that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16722349/2279200) but I am a totally newbe to `sed` and so I am failing.

I also tried something like this

```
sed -i "s|Connector port=[^ ]*|Connector port=8880|g" $CNF_PATH
```

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I want to change the `port="8080"` to `port="8880"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/port="8080"/port="8880"/' inputfile
```

will give the output

```
<Connector port="8880" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

what it does?

`s` command does substitution.

it replaces the pattern `Connector port="8080"` with `Connector port="8880"`

If you want to repace any port number with `8880` you can use

```
sed -r  's/port="[0-9]{4}"/port="8880"/g' inputfile
```

`[0-9]` matches any digit
`{4}` matches the previos pattern for excatly 4 times.

Comment: This does the trick, can you edit your answer to this `sed -i 's/port="8080"/port="8880"/g' inputfile` which is a little more general.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below sed command,

```
sed -i 's|\(Connector port="\)[^"]*"|\18880"|g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also dispense with `sed` and instead use Tomcat's ability to to system property replacement within server.xml:

```
<Connector port="${tomcat-connector-port}" ... />
```

Then, when launching Tomcat, use:

```
$ CATALINA_OPTS="-Dtomcat-connector-port=1234" bin/catalina.sh start
```

Comment: My question refers to a real problem, where my script is responsible for configuring the tomcat but not for start/stop/restart. So your answer is not applicable. However if the problem was different I was going to prefer your approach instead of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

To update specifically the HTTP Connector port :

export TOMCAT_HTTP_PORT="35000"

```
sed -e 's/\(<Connector[ ]*\)\(port=\"[0-9]*\"\)\([ ]*protocol=\"HTTP.*\)/\1port="'$TOMCAT_HTTP_PORT'"\3/' </your/path/to/tomcat>/conf/server.xml
```